# Как сверстать 3 блока адаптивно?

Tags: css3, html5, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать эти блоки не используя background-image?
Как сделать треугольник в правом углу блоков как показано на картинке?
Блоки должны быть адаптивны!

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Тема заезженная уже ...SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 620.41 139.776">
<text y="123.736" x="41.275" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(315.535 -72.407)"/><path d="M0 2.192h192.768l23.434 70.304-23.434 67.28H0z" fill="#f0f" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text
 transform="matrix(.74164 0 0 1.34836 315.535 -72.407)" y="97.928" x="-397.932" style="line-height:12.70264626px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="17.124" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".357">
<tspan style="line-height:12.70264626px" y="97.928" x="-397.932">Lorem Ipsum is simply </tspan>
<tspan style="line-height:12.70264626px" y="110.631" x="-397.932">dummy text of the printing </tspan><tspan style="line-height:12.70264626px" y="123.334" x="-397.932">and typesetting industry.</tspan><tspan style="line-height:12.70264626px" y="136.036" x="-397.932"> Lorem Ipsum has been </tspan><tspan style="line-height:12.70264626px" y="148.739" x="-397.932">the industry&apos;s</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1.14985 0 0 .86968 315.535 -72.407)" y="112.479" x="-262.889" style="line-height:15.7604084px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="30.26" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".63"><tspan y="112.479" x="-262.889">01</tspan></text>
<g>
<path d="M200.176 2.192h192.768l23.435 70.304-23.435 67.28H200.176L225.88 71.74z" fill="#f0f" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/>
<text transform="matrix(.78343 0 0 1.27644 315.535 -72.407)" y="106.053" x="-98.809" style="line-height:16.21080208px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="16.211" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".338">
<tspan style="line-height:16.21080208px" y="106.053" x="-98.809">It is a long established </tspan>
<tspan style="line-height:16.21080208px" y="122.264" x="-98.809">fact that a reader will be</tspan>
<tspan style="line-height:16.21080208px" y="138.475" x="-98.809"> distracted by the readable </tspan><tspan style="line-height:16.21080208px" y="154.686" x="-98.809">content of a page when</tspan></text><text transform="matrix(1.1338 0 0 .882 315.535 -72.407)" y="112.574" x="-88.703" style="line-height:17.148489px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="32.925" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".686"><tspan y="112.574" x="-88.703">02
</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M404.208 0h192.768l23.434 70.304-23.434 67.28H404.208l25.702-68.036z" fill="#f0f" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text style="line-height:16.21080208px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-98.809" y="106.053" transform="matrix(.78343 0 0 1.27644 519.566 -74.599)" font-weight="400" font-size="16.211" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".338"><tspan x="-98.809" y="106.053" style="line-height:16.21080208px">It is a long established </tspan>
<tspan x="-98.809" y="122.264" style="line-height:16.21080208px">fact that a reader will be</tspan><tspan x="-98.809" y="138.475" style="line-height:16.21080208px"> distracted by the readable </tspan><tspan x="-98.809" y="154.686" style="line-height:16.21080208px">content of a page when
</tspan>
</text>
<text style="line-height:17.148489px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-88.703" y="112.574" transform="matrix(1.1338 0 0 .882 519.566 -74.599)" font-weight="400" font-size="32.925" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".686"><tspan x="-88.703" y="112.574">03</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```